# Using Android AccountManager Twitter credentials to create Twitter4J AccessToken

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, accountmanager

I am getting Twitter credentials from the Android AccountManager using the following code:

```
AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(this);
Account account = am.getAccountsByType("com.twitter.android.auth.login")[0];
am.invalidateAuthToken("com.twitter.android.auth.login", null);
am.getAuthToken(account, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token", null, this, createCallback(TOKEN), null);
am.getAuthToken(account, "com.twitter.android.oauth.token.secret", null, this, createCallback(TOKEN_SECRET), null);
```

I'm using the values returned from the callbacks to setup a Twitter4J Twitter object:

```
Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
twitter.setOAuthConsumer(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET);
twitter.setOAuthAccessToken(new AccessToken(token, tokenSecret));
User user = twitter.verifyCredentials();
```

But it generates the following exception when calling verifyCredentials():

```
Exception connecting to twitter
    Received authentication challenge is null
    Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=6f0f59ca or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=200bae40
    TwitterException{exceptionCode=[6f0f59ca-200bae40 1de2170b-e16a1586], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=3.0.2}
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientImpl.request(HttpClientImpl.java:192)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.request(HttpClientWrapper.java:61)
    at twitter4j.internal.http.HttpClientWrapper.get(HttpClientWrapper.java:89)
    at twitter4j.TwitterBaseImpl.fillInIDAndScreenName(TwitterBaseImpl.java:126)
    at twitter4j.TwitterImpl.verifyCredentials(TwitterImpl.java:578)
```

I've tried calling invalidateAuthToken on the AccountManager before requesting the tokens, but that did not make any difference.

I can successfully call verifyCredentials when setting the token and tokenSecret values to those supplied by Twitter for my app, but I need to be able to use the current device users twitter credentials.

Are there any other steps required to use the token and token secret values returned from the AccountManager to setup an AccessToken?

This was tested on an HTC Evo, running Android 2.3.5.

Comment: One note: I don't think `invalidateAuthToken` works without passing the current token string.

Comment: I am also experiencing the same issue! No idea how to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

Check that the clock/time on your phone is correct.

The issue is the twitter server time does not match your phones time.

Comment: I've tried that, I can confirm that the clock is set correctly. It also works if I pass existing token and tokenSecret values, just not when using that values from the AccountManager.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to be able to use the current device users twitter credentials

Sorry, this is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19832978/188926).