# android twitter4j authentication via installed twitter app not browser

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j

i am using twitter4j in my android application to post status to twitter like in this example:
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/

All is working good but the question is:
The authentication is done via browser .. is there any way to detect if twitter app already installed on mobile and authenticate via it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

EDITED: November 27, 2014

Twitter recently released Fabric that does include SSO support. From the [Android docs](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/android/twitter-login):

> When attempting to obtain an authentication token, the Kit will use the locally installed Twitter app to offer a single sign-on experience. If the Kit is unable to access the authentication token through the Twitter app, it falls back to using a web view to finish the OAuth process.

My older response is below.

---

tl;dr 
Currently, SSO with Twitter is not possible on Android.

Longer version:
What you are basically asking for is Single sign-on (SSO), similar to what is available with the Facebook SDK for Android. Twitter has never bothered to even implement their own library for Android, let alone SSO. There are a bunch of people who have asked on the dev forums ([here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4736) and [here](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/20210)) but the standard response is, and I quote,

> We do not currently offer a SDK for Android with the same level of tight integration as is available in iOS5.

Twitter needs to first get their Android app to support SSO. I would suggest using [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/640/) and [Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in) for login instead of Twitter.