# Twitter authentication using Twitter native app Android

Tags: android, twitter, android-authenticator

I have successfully implemented twitter authentication(twitter4j) using webview from my Android app.Is it possible to authenticate without using webview..ie; by triggering phones twitter app ?

Comment: I found a better description here   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027623/android-twitter4j-authentication-via-installed-twitter-app-not-browser?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

No; twitter doesn't provide any such functionality. Facebook and Google do.

Comment: still valid as per 16-aug-2016?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: It's possible...

... when you use Fabric (Twitter's Mobile Development Platform) to login. Somewhere since 2015, the native Twitter App will be used if it's installed on the user's device.